# Oracle PL/SQL arithmetic error

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I am writing a simple arithmetic pl/sql code block to calculate the average of a column of numbers (I know this can be done using the AVG in select statement).

However, I am encountering problems in the arithmetic. I simply can't think of what can be wrong.

Please point out the mistake. It is giving me the following error.
Encountered the symbol "+" when expecting one of the following: (

```
DECLARE
 VMENU MENU%ROWTYPE;
 CURSOR SELECTPRICE IS
 SELECT * FROM MENU;
 AVERAGE NUMBER(7,2):=0;
 SUM NUMBER(7,2):=0;
 COUNT NUMBER(2):=0;

 BEGIN
 OPEN SELECTPRICE;
 LOOP
  FETCH SELECTPRICE INTO VMENU;
  EXIT WHEN SELECTPRICE%NOTFOUND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VMENU.TYPE||' '||VMENU.ITEM||' '||VMENU.PRICE);
  SUM:=SUM+VMENU.PRICE;
  COUNT:=COUNT+1;
 END LOOP;
 AVERAGE:=SUM/COUNT;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(AVERAGE);
 CLOSE SELECTPRICE;
END;
```

Comment: What is your problem? Is it an "arithmetic error" or is it a syntax error ("encountered the symbol "+"...")?

Comment: In Oracle PL/SQL, SUM , COUNT are built in functions, replace it with l_sum , l_count.

Comment: It is a syntax error. "Encountered the symbol"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the variable names `SUM` and `COUNT` to something other than a reserved word.  For example, the code will run if the variables are changed to `V_SUM` and `V_COUNT`.